# How to set a default device in Android Studio (3.1.3) editor?

Tags: android, editor

I have being designing a new layout for my app,
and after 2 hours I have noticed , the preset wasn't set to my device measurements :/, Gosh how can I set my own preset as the **default** on each brand new project?

Thank you all